# How to asynchronously set state in useState hook React

Tags: reactjs

I want to change var value, which is initialized with `useState` hook after some timeout. What is proper way to achieve this?
That's my try:

```
const [msg, setMsg] = useState("Hello");

  const changeMsg = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Buy");
      }, 1000);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setMsg(async () => {
      const res = await changeMsg();
      return res;
    });
  }, []);
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-architecture-9yoqt?file=/src/App.js:103-439)

Comment: [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-darkness-srdf1) - you can't pass the result of `async` function to `setMsg` because an `async` function always returns a promise. You first need to wait for the promise to resolve before passing the promise fulfilment value to the `setMsg` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with this code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("Hello");

  const changeMsg = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Buy");
        setMsg("Another Value");
      }, 1000);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    changeMsg();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">Message is: {msg}</div>;
}
```

The value for variable msg change after 1 second to Another value.

Comment: I think this breaks Rules of hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: @KostyaTresko `setMsg` is a state setter function, its not a hook. So this code doesn't breaks the rules of hooks.

Comment: @Marci Thanks. Btw I didn't downvote your answer

Comment: @KostyaTresko no problem. Did this code worked for you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answer and the solution in the comments are missing a rather important thing, here's my take on the problem:

```
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState("Hello");

    useEffect(()=>{
        const timeout = setTimeout(()=>{
            setMsg("Buy");
        }, 1000);
        return ()=>clearTimeout(timeout);
    }, []); //only run on first render

    return (
        <div className="App">Message is: {msg}</div>
    )
```

Whenever you are using something asynchronous in an effect hook, you should provide a cleanup function. Even here, where the hook runs only once.

Why? Because otherwise you get an error if the component is unmounted before the timeout ran.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React , {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import "./styles.css";

export default function App (){
  const [msg,setMsg] = useState("Hello");
  useEffect(() => {
     const clear = setTimeout(() => setMsg("Busy"),2000);
     return () => {clearTimeout(clear)}
  },[])

  return(<div>
           <h1>{msg}</h1>
        </div>)
  }
```